# Computer crashes after playing Minecraft in fullscreen mode

Tags: crash, display, minecraft

What is happening is if I play Minecraft in fullscreen mode for too long, my computer will suddenly, with out warning go completely blank. The computer sounds like it is still on and running fine, but I cannot get a response out of it, nor can I see anything. In order to reboot properly after this happens I have to power off my PC, switch it off at the back, switch it back on again and boot it back up again.

This did happen before, but it happened with other games, and much quicker. I took it to a repair shop and they said it was a graphics card problem, and replaced my graphics card, and now it is happening again. However as far as I am aware it is only happening with Minecraft.

Have I got some setting which is allocating too much power to minecraft? I am not sure how much memory I have allocated to java, but I have 8GB of RAM, so that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic overheating symptom. First thing is to inspect for blocked air vents or fans. Clean with an air duster and vacuume. Then install temperature monitoring software. Last resort, turn down graphics settings in the game.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked my graphics cards temp with msi afterburner, and it did not seem to go over around 56, and I have heard that a GeForce GTX 560 Ti should function fine at those temperatures. I guess I just need to clean the inside of my PC. Its beginning to look like Winter wonderland in there...